# Linear transformation satisfying $A^2=\lambda A$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A$ be a non-zero linear transformation on a real vector space $V$ of dimension $n$. Let the subspace $V_0 \subset V$ be the image of $V$ under $A$. Let $k=\dim V_0 < n$ and suppose that for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $A^2=\lambda A$. Then
>
> 1) $\lambda=1$
>
> 2) $\det A=\vert \lambda \vert^n$
>
> 3) $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$
>
> 4) There is a nontrivial subspace $V_1 \subset V$ such that $Ax=0, \forall x \in V_1$

My Attempt:

$A^2=\lambda A$ implies $A$ has the eigenvalue $0$ and $\lambda$, so 1) and 3) are false.

But actually 2) and 4) are true, but i have no idea about to prove this.

Any help?

Comment: why you think 1) is false? 1) is possible, indeed the linear operator where it holds that $T^2=T$ are called projections. Maybe 1) is saying that $\lambda=1$ is the unique possible value for $\lambda$? In this case is false.

Comment: Yes. 1) is false for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $\dim V_0 = k<n$ tells you that the kernel (nullspace) of $A$ has positive dimension, so we know that (4) is correct (and $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$). Could $0$ be the only eigenvalue? We could have $A^2 = 0$ (but $A\ne 0$). For example, we could have
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
or a matrix with a number of such $2\times 2$ blocks. So we could have $\lambda = 0$ and both (2) and (3) would hold. ... What if we know that $\lambda\ne 0$ in the given equation?

Comment: if $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\lambda$  and $0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: @LearningMathematics You mean $\lambda$ and $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\lambda=2$. The required conditions hold (with $k=1<n=2$), but statements 1, 2, 3 are false for this.